# Using Collections in a 'For' loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, collections

In a Javascript 'for' loop, is it possible to pass a backbone collection instead of an array? For example: in the sample code below `schools` is a collection , not an array. How is this possible?

```
var selectedSchool;
var addClasses = function(schools){
    selectedSchool = Alloy.Collections.schools.at(0);
       for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++){
    var school = Backbone.Collections.schools.at(i);
    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: schools.get('name'),
        height:'auto', 
   };
```

Here is where `schools` is defined as a collection in the `school` model:

```
exports.definition = {
    config : {
  "defaults": {
     "title": "-",
     "description": "-"
   },
   "adapter": {
     "type": "rest",
     "collection_name": "schools",
     "base_url" : "/schools/",
   }
},

extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        // Extend, override or implement Backbone.Collection 
                 urlRoot: '/schools/',  
                 name: 'schools',
    });

    return Collection;
}
```

}

Any help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: In the loop header you've typed just "schools", but in the body of the loop it's "Backbone.Collections.schools".  Which is it?  Is it both?  Some more code might be helpful because otherwise we can't see the context.

Comment: It's actually sample code that I'm trying to interpret, I figured `schools` was an abbreviation of `Backbone.Collections.schools`, only applicable in for loops

Comment: Why not use [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)?

Comment: OK, well as it stands it doesn't really make sense; it's not at all apparent what the relationship is between the value of "schools" and the value of the property "schools" on "Backbone.Collections".

Comment: Made some edits to provide more context, I hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps have a collection to begin with, convert it to an array, do your job and then convert it back to a collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop for anything you want. They don't have anything in particular to do with arrays, really, other than that it's common to use a `for` loop to iterate through the elements of an array. The real crux of your question is whether the "schools" object has a "length" attribute. If it does, and if the value is a number, then there's no problem at all.